# how to update json rdd using python in spark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark

iam trying to find a way to update json rdd in spark using python. please find below the sample json iam using and the python code . iam not able to update the json. help is welcome

my input file input/json.text1:

```
{
    "text":"From: USERNAME@leland.Stanford.EDU (USER NAME)\nSubject: When does Fred McGriff of the Padres become a free agent?\nOrganization: DSG, Stanford University, CA 94305, USAn",
    "label_name":"rec.sport.baseball",
    "label":9
}
```

python code:

```
import sys
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
sc = SparkContext("spark://dev1:7077", "testconnection")
data_raw = sc.textFile('/input/json.text1')
data = data_raw.map(lambda line: json.loads(line))
data_pared = data.map(lambda line:(['label_name']):  "new value ")
print data_pared.first()
sc.stop()
```

Comment: What does your print show up?

Comment: iam getting run time error. iam not finding a way to update the json file